# How to create @KafkaListener dynamically for each topic configured in property in Java springboot

Tags: spring-kafka

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@Slf4j
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

@Value("#{'${kafka.topicNames}'.split(',')}")
  private String[] topics;

  @Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties());

}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory defaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory() {
    return new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
}

@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar kafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar(
        KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory) {

    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar = new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar();
    registrar.setContainerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory);
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(defaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory());

    for (String topic : topics) {
        //KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry endpointRegistry = new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry();
        MessageListener<String, String> messageListener = new KafkaMessageListener(endpointRegistry);
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topic);
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(messageListener);

        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> kafkaListenerEndpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setId(topic);
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setBean(messageListener);
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setMethod(KafkaMessageListener.class.getDeclaredMethod("onMessage", ConsumerRecord.class));
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setTopics(topic);

        registrar.registerEndpoint(kafkaListenerEndpoint, kafkaListenerContainerFactory);

    }

    return registrar;
}

}
```

When trying to generate separate kafka listener for each topic configured in the property file, getting the below error.

Is there any other option available to achieve this?

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [../config/kafka/KafkaListenerConfig.class]: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpoint, org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory)" because **"this.endpointRegistry" is null**

Answer (score 0):

The `@EnableKafka` registers for us a `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.
And that one has this API:

```
/**
 * Create a message listener container for the given {@link KafkaListenerEndpoint}.
 * <p>This create the necessary infrastructure to honor that endpoint
 * with regards to its configuration.
 * @param endpoint the endpoint to add
 * @param factory the listener factory to use
 * @see #registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpoint, KafkaListenerContainerFactory, boolean)
 */
public void registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint, KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
```

So, consider to use that one instead of manual `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar` creation.